# How do I replace an entire line that matches several words in Powershell regex?

Tags: powershell

How do I get Powershell regex to replace an entire line in a file from a match containing several keywords?

I have the following so far where the line to replace is already defined in the **$search_parameter** variable and the search keyword is a single word stored in the **$namefile** parameter:

```
(Get-Content "C:\path\txt.file") -replace "`^$namefile`"/>", $search_parameter | Set-Content "C:\path\txt.file"
```

I'm struggling with the regex to replace to extend from the beginning of the line to the **$namefile** variable and a few characters after it. I thought a ^ would do the trick, but since I'm dealing with strings and other characters, I don't think it'd work encapsulated in double-quotes.

Example config file:

```
  <configuration-file>
    <section name="section1">
      <entry name="name1" value="value1"/>
      <entry name="name2" value="value2"/>
    </section>
    <section name="section2">
      <entry name="someothername" value="someothervalue"/>
    </section>
  </configuration-file>
```

So with the example config file, the **$search_parameter** would for instance be '428' and $namefile would be 'value2', but the -replace parameter would be set to expand to the entire line that 'value2' is based on. I got it to work without focusing on the entire line and just replacing 'value2', but I'm trying to replace and add other XML values as needed if that makes any sense.

Comment: Is your original file structured data? Such as XML?

Comment: Yes, it does contain XML-style tags.

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you are parsing as well as what you want to extract/replace?

Comment: So here's the syntax for the config file I'm attempting to edit:

Comment: Just did. I'm finding is easier to do that instead of adding things in via comments. Thanks

Comment: @xorLogic This would be a lot easier to do with .net's xml functionality in powershell.  Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522980/select-xml-element-by-attribute-value-and-add-an-element

Comment: In general directly editing structured data files is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put two and two together. From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522980/select-xml-element-by-attribute-value-and-add-an-element), here is what you were asking for... replacing "value2" with "428"

```
$Path = "C:\temp\testfile.txt"
$xml = [xml](get-content $Path)
($xml.'configuration-file'.section.entry | Where-Object {$_.value -eq "value2"}).value = '428'
$xml.Save("C:\temp\testfile_New.txt")
```

Here is the output of the new file:

```
<configuration-file>
    <section name="section1">
        <entry name="name1" value="value1" />
        <entry name="name2" value="428" />
    </section>
    <section name="section2">
        <entry name="someothername" value="someothervalue" />
    </section>
</configuration-file>
```

Comment: I see. Yep, that's it! Thanks!