# foreach-object if return , returning all value issue

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have this weird ouput that being generated. $abc is an xml with around 200 nodes
I tried to search for a specific element with hostname cat01.pdx30, but the below seems to print out all hostname from abc, any ideas?

```
($abc.DeviceMetaData) | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($PSItem.Device.HostName -match  [regex]::Escape("cat01.pdx30")) {
        return $psitem.Device.HostName 
    }
}
```

$abc looks something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DeviceMetaData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Device HostName="cat02.pdx30">
    <Property Name="Home">Region</Property>
  </Device>
  <Device HostName="cat01.mwh01">
    <Property Name="AclFile" />
    <Property Name="AnchorPresent">False</Property>
    <Property Name="CloudType">Public</Property>
    <Property Name="ConfigTemplateFile">iper_Ce.xml</Property>
    <Property Name="DcCode">mwh01</Property>
  </Device>
  <Device HostName="ALB70-RME71-226-01OSP">
    <Property Name="OpticalEnabled">True</Property>
  </Device>
</DeviceMetaData>
```

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the XML file, for us to understand how it is structured?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the sample data for others to see the necessary details to help you with your question.

Comment: updated now on the main thread

Comment: From what you have described, it seems like you are trying to find a node with an attribute value. Please consider looking at this existing question: [Select XML element by attribute value and add an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522980/select-xml-element-by-attribute-value-and-add-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other method, with XPath:

```
[xml] $xml=get-content "C:\temp\test.xml"
$xml.SelectNodes('//DeviceMetaData/Device[@HostName="cat01.mwh01"]/Property[@Name="DcCode"]')."#text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data sample, you **didn't** instructed powershell to handle the **child elements** of the DeviceMetaData element.

```
$abc.DeviceMetaData.Device | ForEach-Object { 
    if($_.HostName -match [regex]::Escape("cat01.pdx30")) {
        $PSItem.Hostname
    }
}
```

The above example tells PowerShell to traverse all **Device** elements. Foreach of these objects it will match against the HostName attribute and if there is a match it simply outputs the HostName.

Please consider not using the **return** keyword in PowerShell. The return keyword breaks execution from the current scope, which is something entirely different than just outputting some data.

Please note that your sample data and your search condition isn't the same. In your data there isn't any **"cat01.pdx30"** HostName. Just so you don't think the solution doesn't work.

**Update**
Based on the new requirements this example does what is expected.

```
$abc.DeviceMetaData.Device | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.HostName -match [regex]::Escape("cat01.mwh01")) {
        $PSItem.Property | Where-Object Name -eq "DcCode" | Select-Object "#text"
    }
}
```

In the new example we traverse all **Property** elements, filters them by using the **Where-Object** and selects the inner text of the attribute with the *magical* "#text" that instructs powershell to read the value of the attribute and not the attribute with name and value.

Comment: actually my purpose is to find a particular device say "cat01.pdx30" and return the DcCode value .. that the reason I was passing on $abc.DeviceMetaData

Comment: Did you see the new example I shared within my update?